# Extending Inner class

Tags: scala, inner-classes

I am trying to replicate my problem on a smaller example.
I am getting compilation error at the shown location in the following code snippet.

```
class Outer {
    class Inner
}

object OuterUtil {
  val obj = new Outer
  object xyz extends obj.Inner
  //do something with xyz
}

//-------------------
object OuterUtil2 {
    var m_obj: Outer = null

    def createOuter() = {
        m_obj = new Outer
    }

    def anotherMethod() {
        //Compilation error here: stable identifier required, 
        //but OuterUtil2.this.m_obj found.
        object xyz extends m_obj.Inner
    }
}

object Test {
    OuterUtil2.createOuter
    OuterUtil2.anotherMethod
}
```

`OuterUtil` is working fine. 
In `OuterUtil2`, I am splitting the functionality into two functions. I am storing the `Outer` instance `m_obj` as a member `var`. The `createOuter` method creates and stores the `Outer` instance in `m_obj`. In `anotherMethod`, I am getting compilation error. How to fix `OuterUtil2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to solve the problem with your function, here is a solution (by fixing the `var` to a `val` in the function)

```
def anotherMethod = {
  val obj = m_obj
  new obj.Inner
}
```

Another solution would be to use some options, however to overpass the stable identifier method, you have to define a `val` out of `m_obj` value. This solution is more elegant because you don't have null pointer exceptions if `m_obj` is not defined.

```
object OuterUtil2 {
  var m_obj: Option[Outer] = None

  def createOuter {
    m_obj = Some(new Outer)
  }

  def anotherMethod = {
    m_obj match{
      case None => None
      case Some(_) => val obj = m_obj.get; Some(new obj.Inner)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The prefix of a type (ie, the `m_obj` in `m_obj.Inner`) must be a stable value; a `var` doesn't cut it. You could make that a `val` and move the initialization out of `createOuter`.